# Is it possible to specify the WRITETIME in a Cassandra INSERT command?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-c++-driver

I am having a problem where a few INSERT commands are viewed as being send simultaneously on the Cassandra side when my code clearly does not send them simultaneously. (When you get a little congestion on the network, then the problem happens, otherwise, everything works just fine.)

What I am thinking would solve this problem is a way for me to be able to specify the WRITETIME myself. From what I recall, that was possible in thrift, but maybe not (i.e. we could read it for sure.)

So something like this (to simulate the TTL):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3) USING WRITETIME = 123;
```

The problem I'm facing is overwriting the same data and once in a while the update is ignored because it ends up with the same or even an older timestamp (probably because it is sent to a different node and the time of each node is slightly different and since the C++ process uses threads, it can be send before/after without your control...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic syntax you're looking for is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (1,2) USING TIMESTAMP 123456789000
```

Be very cautious using this approach - make sure you use the right units (microseconds, typically).

*You can override the meaning of time stamps in some cases - it's a sneaky trick we've used in the past to do clever things like first-write-wins and even stored leaderboard values in the TIMESTAMP field so highest score would be persisted, but you should REALLY understand the concept before trying these (deletes become nontrivial)*

Comment: I'm hit by reordering of my messages, unfortunately, and the C++ driver does not seem to do anything to palliate. Maybe this is an expected limitation of the database, however, by using `TIMESTAMP`, it looks like I can send messages that the C++ driver reorders and still get the correct results. (about reordering, see "Assumptions, Network, Messages may be lost, reordered, or duplicated." in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Letting your application manually manipulate the timestamp field to send monotonically increasing timestamps to avoid reordering problems is reasonable - to be honest, I thought most of the datastax drivers did that already. Apparently the cpp driver has a generator that provides this functionality explicitly: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/2.1/cpp-driver/reference/clientsideTimestamps.html